# Remapping key to <Nop> not working

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'm trying to remap my Backspace key to do nothing in insert mode (want to start using more x and other different ways that are better for deletion in vim)

I added in my `.vimrc` this line:

```
inoremap <BS> <Nop>
```

But after restarting my `vim` the backspace still deletes a character.

What am I doing wrong?

This is part of my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set laststatus=2
set background=dark
set number
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
set autochdir

set noswapfile
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set fileencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
set gdefault
set smartcase
set scrolloff=5
let mapleader=","
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let g:ag_working_path_mode="ar"

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'

let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'

 set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'

set hidden
nmap <leader>T :enew<cr>
nmap <leader>l :bnext<cr>
nmap <leader>h :bprev<cr>
nmap <leader>bq :bp <BAR> bd #<CR>
nmap <leader>bl :ls<CR>

nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>
nnoremap <leader>q :q<cr>

noremap > >><cr>
noremap < <<<cr>

let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
            \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$|/node_modules/',
            \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
            \ 'link': 'some_bad_symbolic_links',
            \ }
let g:ctrlp_dotfiles = 0
j
"autocmd BufWritePre * :normal gg=G
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsNoPythoWarning = 1

" Syntastic
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

" C tags
nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>. :CtrlPTag<CR>
inoremap <leader>; <C-o>A;
nnoremap <leader>; A;

set diffopt+=vertical
inoremap <BS> <Nop>
"inoremap <Del> <Nop>
```

Comment: I used your vimrc but removed the `pathogen#infect()` and the mapping works correctly. So I suspect one of your plugin to cause the problem. Can you try to comment the execution of pathogen and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Yes. You are right. That is one of the plugins.

Comment: Before posting on this site I strongly recommend that you read (and apply) [How do I debug my vimrc](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1841) it will help you spot a vast majority of your problems.

Comment: @statox Yes, I was not aware of this. I will do it now.

Comment: Great! In the other hand don't hesitate to ask your questions when you already have done some debugging, the community of this site is generally pretty good to give fast and good answers :-)

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce your issue by starting Vim without `nocompatible` set.

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE
```

It seems that the `inoremap` is not in Vi, so it won't do the map if you don't add the `nocompatible` option.

e.g. it works with:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
```

Also, as a general rule, you may want to start your `vimrc` with

```
set nocompatible
```

**Note:** next time have a look at [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: Sorry that is my bad, I use <BS>. Editing question now

Comment: OK, but I got it working here, strange...

Comment: Yep, I know. Suppose to be really simple. Not sure why this is not working for me.

Comment: have you tried without any config in you vimrc file ?

Comment: can you try with and without the `compatible` option set? It doesn't work without also.

Comment: I have it on. 
I have added my .vimrc .. if it will help

Comment: It was the auto-pairs plugin .